# Post a document in to a page not in preview

Tags: sharepoint-online, document, homepage

I have seen people posting documents in to news pages or even home pages of team sites, but not in preview file mode which actually displays the content of the document, but rather showing that little nice thumbnail. Just as recent documents displays documents. Please picture below:

[image]

Anybody has done that before?
(So sorry if I couldn't explain that sufficiently well)

edit: sorry everybody, I think I didn't managed to explain that well, eventually. What I am trying to do is to insert a document in my home page and display it as the pictures posted below. I am stuck, because when I go to file viewer then select a document to post and it would place the document in opened preview to scroll down and see it's contents. I don't want that. I just want the default thumbnail to be displayed and if a user wants he can click the document to open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported to customize thumbnails in the web parts on SharePoint modern page. They use the first image for documents and pages when there is no banner image used.

The only OOB solution would be manually add banner image to the first page of the document so that it will display as thumbnail.

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

If you want to display a document with only thumbnail on a modern page, I suggest you use **[Highlighted content web part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd)**.

For example, I want to display a PDF file whose **Title** is "Licensing_Microsoft_SharePoint_Server" in the document library "Documents".

Here’s the configuration for the web part and the outcome.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Chelsea_MSFT. Sorry, I think I didn't explained it well, so let me retry. I am not trying to customize the thumbnail of a document in recent activity docs. What I am trying to do is to insert a document in my home page and display it as the pictures above you attached I am stuck because when I go to file viewer and select a document to post, it would place the document in opened preview to scroll down and see it's contents. I don't want that. I just want the default thumbnail to be displayed and if a user want he can click the document to open it.

Comment: @GunnRos86 I’ve edited the answer to include more information. Please check the update.

Comment: I gave a check mark to your post, cause it provided a workaround to this problem. Thanks a lot and keep it up!!

Answer (score 0):

Using the **file viewer** web part we can do this,earlier this web part was called document viewer webpart.

Microsoft documentation says:

"Use the **File viewer** web part to insert a file on your page. File types you can insert include **Excel, Word, PowerPoint, Visio, PDFs, 3D models, and more.**"

Refer to the below MSDN article to configure the file viewer webpart :

[Use the File viewer web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-file-viewer-web-part-e53a9602-e7b3-4fff-9126-de2f18d1900c?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I've done that and it places the document opened to preview it's content. Whilst I am refering to insert there a thumbnail of the document.

Answer (score 0):

As what i have understood (Please correct me if im wrong), you wanted the Thumbnail of the document but the recent document webpart thumbnail is not showing the actual file image?

*please ignore sentences below if Im assuming it wrong

In that case, ootb document webpart is showing the first page of the document as the preview, we can't do anything about it for now if you wanted the other document page content shown as the preview but if its really needed, we can still do it with webpart customization using [Spfx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part) to build a specific webpart for it (but actually is a overkill for the purpose of just an image preview), Anyhow its one of the options you can consider.

Hope the concept helps! Happy learning!